# Ajax error - 0 after a long php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to send the url of a file (csv file) located on the server to my php script so as to process it.

The csv file contains telephone calls. If i have a file with even 10.000 calls everything is ok. But if i try a big file with like for example 20000 calls then i get an Ajax Error 0 . I check for server responce with firebug but i get none.

This behaviour occurs after like 40mins of w8ing for the php script to end. So why do i get this error on big files only? Does it have to do with apache, mysql or the server itself? Anyone able to help will be my personal hero cause this is driving me nuts.

I need a way to figure out whats happening exactly but firebug wont return a server responce. Any other way i can find out whats happening?

I checked the php error log and it reports nothing on the matter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use databases, not files.

Comment: He is processing a CSV, not 'using' files.. how come you know he is using a db or not?

Comment: Do you really wait for 40 minutes?

Comment: I am reading a  -csv file line by line and inmporting the data in a database, i am not working with files. Furthermore i Know its not the execution time because i ve dealt with that problem before. At that point the response from the server mentioned the timeout though so i knew what to fix. Now it doesnt. And last but not least , I am not simply w8ing for 40 mins. The script runs fine because its processing lines from the csv file into the database but after about 40 mins it just stops. With no timeout messages or anything

Answer (score 3):

The script may have timed out:

See your php.ini file

```
max_execution_time
max_input_time  ;# for the max time an input can be processed
```

Were your PHP.ini is depends on your enviroment, more information: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php

Comment: This also could be the webserver (apache, other?) timeout, php has its own, the webserver usually has another.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

**max_input_time**

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET. It is measured from the moment of receiving all data on the server to the start of script execution.

**max_execution_time**

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

Also

Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details.

Comment: I am using a local server in which i have access although i m not really sure what should i check, with xampp. Any suggestions as to what i should check? max_input and max_execution time were already changed to unlimited.

Answer (score -1):

First enable php error by placing below code at top of the php file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then as Shamil explained in this answer, checkout your max_execution_time settings of your php.

To check max_execution time, open your php.ini file and search for that, and then change it to a maximum value of say one hour (3600).

I hope this will fix your issue.

Thank you

Comment: He is talking about 40min of execution time.. 3600 is not the answer :)